# Python tensorflow complex number operation

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am doing modelling and variational inference by Edward(1.3.5) and Tensorflow(1.6.0, -gpu version). However, when trying to do some operations with complex numbers, an error happened "ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype complex64 for Tensor with dtype float32". Here is a simplify example but also causes the same error:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.complex(1., 1.) * tf.sqrt(1.)**2
```

It seems like the dtype between the result of complex and sqrt are conflicting?
Furthermore, I also try to convert the result of sqrt into float64, but some error received:

```
tf.complex(1., 1.) * tf.cast(sqrt(1.), tf.float64)**2
```

Any solutions? 
Thank You.

Comment: cast it to complex64 instead of float64

Comment: Yes, it works!! Thank you.

Comment: can you upvote, and accept my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is to cast the number to a complex64 instead of a float 64

```
tf.complex(1., 1.) * tf.cast(sqrt(1.), tf.complex64)**2
```